# Is there an efficient way to approximate (a / b)^n where a, b, and n are unsigned integers?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, exponent

[Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is an algorithm that quickly computes a<sup>n</sup>, where `a` and `n` are signed integers. (It does so in O(log n) multiplications).

Is there a similar algorithm, that instead computes (a / b)<sup>n</sup>, where `a`, `b`, and `n` are all unsigned integers? The problem with the obvious approach (i.e., computing a<sup>n</sup> / b<sup>n</sup>) is that it will return wrong results due to integer overflow on the intermediate values.

I don't have floating points in the host language, only ints.

I'm okay with an approximate answer.

Comment: Why not do the calculation in floating point?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I don't have floating points in the host language, only ints. Not sure how to implement floating-point (and the respective`exp`/`floor`) from ints, but if it is easy enough, that'd be a valid answer.

Comment: "okay with an approximate answer" is very broad. It includes q=a/b, q=q^n

Comment: Working on a quick 'n' dirty implementation of Feynman's algorithm. Stay tuned...

Comment: @DavidEisenstat yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want excellent accuracy for the value of (a/b)^n, where a, b, and n are unsigned integers and you do not have floating point arithmetic available--use extended-precision integer calculations to find a^n and b^n, then divide the two.

Some languages, such as Python, have extended-precision integer arithmetic built in. If your language does not have it, look for a package that implements it. If you cannot do that, just make your own package. It is not that hard--such a package was an assignment in my second-semester computer science class back in the day. The multiplications and powers are fairly straightforward; the most difficult part is the division, even if you just want the quotient and remainder. But "most difficult" does not mean "very difficult" and you could probably do it. The second must difficult routine is printing the extended integer to decimal format.

The basic idea is to store each integer in an array or list of regular unsigned integers, where is integer is a "digit" in arithmetic with a large base. You want to be able to handle the product of any two digits, so if your machine has 32-bit integers and you have no way of handling 64-bit integers, store "digits" of 16 bits each. The larger the "digit" the faster the calculations. If your calculations are few and your printing to decimal is frequent, use a power of 10 such as 10000 for each "digit".

Ask if you need more detail.

Comment: That answer made me so happy! You're completely right, I could use extended-precision integer arithmetic and get excellent results. It would be too costly to implement it on the [Ethereum Network](https://www.ethereum.org/), though, since it charges harsh fees on all the allocations that bigNums would require; in that case, I'd rather trade some precision for efficiency. Nether less, I wasn't very clear about that on the question and this is an excellent answer to what was asked, so I'll just accept it for future readers! Thank you :)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pow implementation in fixed point based on Feynman's log algorithm. It's quick and somewhat dirty; C libraries tend to use a polynomial approximation, but that approach is more complicated, and I'm not sure how well it would translate to fixed point.

```
// powFraction approximates (a/b)**n.
func powFraction(a uint64, b uint64, n uint64) uint64 {
    if a == 0 || b == 0 || a < b {
        panic("powFraction")
    }
    return expFixed((logFixed(a) - logFixed(b)) * n)
}

// logFixed approximates 2**58 * log2(x). [Feynman]
func logFixed(x uint64) uint64 {
    if x == 0 {
        panic("logFixed")
    }
    // Normalize x into [2**63, 2**64).
    n := numberOfLeadingZeros(x)
    x <<= n
    p := uint64(1 << 63)
    y := uint64(0)
    for k := uint(1); k <= 63; k++ {
        // Warning: if q > x-p, then p + q may overflow.
        if q := p >> k; q <= x-p {
            p += q
            y += table[k-1]
        }
    }
    return uint64(63-n)<<58 + y>>6
}

// expFixed approximately inverts logFixed.
func expFixed(y uint64) uint64 {
    n := 63 - uint(y>>58)
    y <<= 6
    p := uint64(1 << 63)
    for k := uint(1); k <= 63; k++ {
        if z := table[k-1]; z <= y {
            p += p >> k
            y -= z
        }
    }
    return p >> n
}

// numberOfLeadingZeros returns the number of leading zeros in the word x.
// [Hacker's Delight]
func numberOfLeadingZeros(x uint64) uint {
    n := uint(64)
    if y := x >> 32; y != 0 {
        x = y
        n = 32
    }
    if y := x >> 16; y != 0 {
        x = y
        n -= 16
    }
    if y := x >> 8; y != 0 {
        x = y
        n -= 8
    }
    if y := x >> 4; y != 0 {
        x = y
        n -= 4
    }
    if y := x >> 2; y != 0 {
        x = y
        n -= 2
    }
    if x>>1 != 0 {
        return n - 2
    }
    return n - uint(x)
}

// table[k-1] approximates 2**64 * log2(1 + 2**-k). [MPFR]
var table = [...]uint64{
    10790653543520307104, // 1
    5938525176524057593,  // 2
    3134563013331062591,  // 3
    1613404648504497789,  // 4
    818926958183105433,   // 5
    412613322424486499,   // 6
    207106307442936368,   // 7
    103754619509458805,   // 8
    51927872466823974,    // 9
    25976601570169168,    // 10
    12991470209511302,    // 11
    6496527847636937,     // 12
    3248462157916594,     // 13
    1624280643531991,     // 14
    812152713665686,      // 15
    406079454902306,      // 16
    203040501980337,      // 17
    101520444623942,      // 18
    50760270720599,       // 19
    25380147462480,       // 20
    12690076756788,       // 21
    6345039134781,        // 22
    3172519756487,        // 23
    1586259925518,        // 24
    793129974578,         // 25
    396564990243,         // 26
    198282495860,         // 27
    99141248115,          // 28
    49570624104,          // 29
    24785312063,          // 30
    12392656035,          // 31
    6196328018,           // 32
    3098164009,           // 33
    1549082005,           // 34
    774541002,            // 35
    387270501,            // 36
    193635251,            // 37
    96817625,             // 38
    48408813,             // 39
    24204406,             // 40
    12102203,             // 41
    6051102,              // 42
    3025551,              // 43
    1512775,              // 44
    756388,               // 45
    378194,               // 46
    189097,               // 47
    94548,                // 48
    47274,                // 49
    23637,                // 50
    11819,                // 51
    5909,                 // 52
    2955,                 // 53
    1477,                 // 54
    739,                  // 55
    369,                  // 56
    185,                  // 57
    92,                   // 58
    46,                   // 59
    23,                   // 60
    12,                   // 61
    6,                    // 62
    3,                    // 63
}
```

Comment: @MaiaVictor It's [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is looking for a constant-space solution, I've kind of solved the issue with binomial expansions, which are a decent approximation. I'm using the following code:

```
// Computes `k * (1+1/q) ^ N`, with precision `p`. The higher
// the precision, the higher the gas cost. It should be
// something around the log of `n`. When `p == n`, the
// precision is absolute (sans possible integer overflows).
// Much smaller values are sufficient to get a great approximation.
function fracExp(uint k, uint q, uint n, uint p) returns (uint) {
  uint s = 0;
  uint N = 1;
  uint B = 1;
  for (uint i = 0; i < p; ++i){
    s += k * N / B / (q**i);
    N  = N * (n-i);
    B  = B * (i+1);
  }
  return s;
}
```

Which simply computes the `p` first terms of the binomial expansion of `(1 + r)^N`, where `r` is a small positive real number. I posted a more thoughtful explanation at [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10425/is-there-any-efficient-way-to-compute-the-exponentiation-of-a-fraction-and-an-in/10432#10432).